# KSQL: stream select query is not populating the data

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

Select query against created stream on topic in KSQL , is not giving the result where as respective topics are holing the message .

**Step1:** producer command :

```
root@masbidw1.usa.corp.ad:/usr/hdp/3.0.1.0-187/confluentclient/confluent-5.2.2> bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list masbidw1.usa.corp.ad:9092 --topic emptable3
>TEST1,TEST2,TEST3
```

**Step-2**:Print command in KSQL terminal :

```
ksql> print 'emptable3' from beginning;
Format:STRING
8/16/19 10:57:45 AM EDT , NULL , TEST1,TEST2,TEST3
8/16/19 11:00:09 AM EDT , NULL , TEST1,TEST2,TEST3
8/16/19 11:00:16 AM EDT , NULL , TEST1,TEST2,TEST3
8/16/19 2:17:36 PM EDT , NULL , TEST1,TEST2,TEST3
```

Consumer is not giving the result without partition number :

```
root@masbidw1.usa.corp.ad:/usr/hdp/3.0.1.0-187/confluentclient/confluent-5.2.2> bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server masbidw1.usa.corp.ad:9092 --topic emptable3 --from-beginning
```

So added partition number in consumer command and it is giving the message out .

```
root@masbidw1.usa.corp.ad:/usr/hdp/3.0.1.0-187/confluentclient/confluent-5.2.2> bin/kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server masbidw1.usa.corp.ad:9092 --topic emptable3 --from-beginning  --partition 0
TEST1,TEST2,TEST3
TEST1,TEST2,TEST3
TEST1,TEST2,TEST3
TEST1,TEST2,TEST3
```

Setting up the earliest property in KSQL terminal

```
'auto.offset.reset'='earliest'
```

creating the KSQL stream:

```
CREATE STREAM emptable2_stream (column1 STRING, column2 STRING, column3 STRING) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='emptable3', VALUE_FORMAT='DELIMITED');
```

selecting the value from KSQL stream:

```
ksql> select * from EMPTABLE3_STREAM;

Press CTRL-C to interrupt
```

But No response . Even new data itself is not getting queried from the stream

Describe extended

```
ksql> describe extended EMPTABLE3_STREAM;

Name                 : EMPTABLE3_STREAM
Type                 : STREAM
Key field            :
Key format           : STRING
Timestamp field      : Not set - using <ROWTIME>
Value format         : DELIMITED
Kafka topic          : emptable3 (partitions: 1, replication: 1)

 Field   | Type
-------------------------------------
 ROWTIME | BIGINT           (system)
 ROWKEY  | VARCHAR(STRING)  (system)
 COLUMN1 | VARCHAR(STRING)
 COLUMN2 | VARCHAR(STRING)
 COLUMN3 | VARCHAR(STRING)
-------------------------------------

Local runtime statistics
------------------------


(Statistics of the local KSQL server interaction with the Kafka topic emptable3)
```

Comment: you create emptable2_stream and you select on EMPTABLE3_STREAM... just tried what you described and for me it works with emptable2_stream.

Comment: Thanks for Your response. Could you please share the KSQL server setup ?

Comment: I did a quick run with the local confluent docker setup... https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html